# How to put an image behind text in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, css-position, background-position

I want an image to be displayed **behind** some text in an `<h1>` tag. But when I add the image it replaces the text and pushes the text below it.

Screenshots : [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBiYQ.png) and [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuZU2.png)

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
header,
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: CGF Locust Resistance;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: lightgray;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1.5px #000;
}
header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: .5px solid #b3b3b3;
}
nav {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: .5px solid #b3b3b3;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: CGF Locust Resistance;
  font-size: 12.5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
#omen {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the html code as well?

Answer (score 2):

Set the image as a background-image of header. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 2):

```
h1 {
  background: url(the/filepath/to/your/image.jpg) no-repeat center 100px;
  background-size: 400px auto;
  }
```

That's approximately how you would use a background image in this situation. `center 100px` means horizontally centered and 100px from the top (in relation to the `h1` element).

Answer (score 0):

```
h1 {
  position : abosolute; 
}
```

This should do the trick but it is preferable to use ids instead of changeing the h tags everywhere on your side

Answer (score 0):

Put this parameter to the image object in css (example creating custom classes) :

```
.image{
    position: relative;
}
```

And this one to the text :

```
.text{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Of course, you have to set this classes to it's respective objects. Hope it helps !